# Spark - Csv data split with scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

```
test.csv
name,key1,key2
A,1,2
B,1,3
C,4,3
```

I want to change this data like this (as dataset or rdd)

```
whatIwant.csv
name,key,newkeyname
A,1,KEYA
A,2,KEYB
B,1,KEYA
B,3,KEYB
C,4,KEYA
C,3,KEYB
```

I loaded data with read method.

```
val df = spark.read
            .option("header", true)
            .option("charset", "euc-kr")
            .csv(csvFilePath)
```

I can load each dataset like (name, key1) or (name, key2), and union them by union, but want to do this in single spark session.
Any idea of this?

---

Those are not working.

```
val df2 = df.select( df("TAG_NO"), df.map { x => (x.getAs[String]("MK_VNDRNM"), x.getAs[String]("WK_ORD_DT")) })

val df2 = df.select( df("TAG_NO"), Seq(df("TAG_NO"), df("WK_ORD_DT")))
```

Comment: Did you try `explode` function from DataFrame?

Comment: nope. i'll try with explode. thanks :)

Comment: Since key1 and key2 are not in single column, I think explode is not the right answer.

Comment: You can convert key1, key2 as tuple by applying map function.

Comment: could you give me some example for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `explode` and a `udf`:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("A", 1, 2), ("B", 1, 3), ("C", 4, 3)).toDF("name", "key1", "key2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, key1: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+----+----+----+
|name|key1|key2|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   1|   2|
|   B|   1|   3|
|   C|   4|   3|
+----+----+----+

scala> val explodeUDF = udf((v1: String, v2: String) => Vector((v1, "Key1"), (v2, "Key2")))
explodeUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,StringType,true)),true),Some(List(StringType, StringType)))

scala> df = df.withColumn("TMP", explode(explodeUDF($"key1", $"key2"))).drop("key1", "key2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, TMP: struct<_1: string, _2: string>]

scala> df = df.withColumn("key", $"TMP".apply("_1")).withColumn("new key name", $"TMP".apply("_2"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, TMP: struct<_1: string, _2: string> ... 2 more fields]

scala> df = df.drop("TMP")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, key: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+----+---+------------+
|name|key|new key name|
+----+---+------------+
|   A|  1|        Key1|
|   A|  2|        Key2|
|   B|  1|        Key1|
|   B|  3|        Key2|
|   C|  4|        Key1|
|   C|  3|        Key2|
+----+---+------------+
```

Comment: profit! It's bit different from my origin problem but can make it with this. thanks alot :)